# MySQL Select multiple rows from one row in 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this situation:

```
Table A (Ex. Dog's name):
ID | Name
1  | Nabu
2  | Lapo
3  | Kim
3  | Bau

Table B (Ex. Dog's characteristics):
ID | AID | BID | BV
1  |  1  |  1  |  1
2  |  1  |  2  |  1
3  |  1  |  3  |  0
4  |  2  |  1  |  1
5  |  2  |  2  |  0
6  |  2  |  3  |  1
7  |  3  |  1  |  0
8  |  3  |  2  |  1
9  |  3  |  3  |  1
10 |  4  |  1  |  1
11 |  4  |  2  |  1
12 |  4  |  3  |  1
```

I need to make an "exact search" in A using the B characteristics fields

Ex.

```
(BID = 1 && BV = 1) AND (BID = 2 && BV = 1)  have to return A.ID = 1 & 4
(BID = 1 && BV = 0) AND (BID = 2 && BV = 1)  have to return A.ID = 3
```

How can i do this in 1 or less then one query each characteristic and a comparaction!?

Thanks!

Comment: In less than one query?

Comment: One separate query each Dog Characteristic!
Or having to check each characteristic for each dog and search for a right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select AID
from table B
group by AID
having sum(BID = 1 AND BV = 1) > 0 and
       sum(BID = 2 AND BV = 1) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that meet one of the conditions.  Your logic requires that both be present, so the number of rows needs to be bigger than 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you join the table on itself:

```
SELECT A.id FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B as B1 on A.ID = B1.AID
LEFT JOIN B as B2 on A.ID = B2.AID and B1.ID != B2.ID
WHERE
(B1.BID = 1 && B1.BV = 1) AND (B2.BID = 2 && B2.BV = 1)
```

You should be able to find all rows in A where you two matching entries from B where the B.IDs are different.

Comment: That's awesome, works grate! I really forget to test inception-join! Thank!

Comment: Interestingly there is actually an issue with this solution, it will only return the lower of the two IDs that match. Alternatively maybe I dont understand the logic for 1 and 4 being returned for the first query. Hopefully the idea itself helpd though.

Comment: I have removed the  "and B1.ID < B2.ID" and in my little test works great! I have to test in some bigger and a peaty much real example this night!

Comment: The bigger problem will be if I have 10 or more different characteristics, this mean re-join the same table 10 or more times.

But maybe is not a big problem...

Comment: In that situation the suggestion with the solution provided by @GordonLinoff may work better.

Comment: Thanks, i'm a big NOOB! Thanks to both!